# Should I follow up with the Hiring Manager after getting rejected?

Tags: interviewing

I found a job in a new career (although related to my current) that interested me. It just so happened that I also had a friend who worked at the company of the new job. So, I applied and I told my friend who kindly gave me a reference. My friend sent the reference via email to the hiring manager and cc'd me on the email.

I interviewed and it did not go very well. I know some of my takeaways that I need to work on, but I'd like to ask the hiring manager since this is a different career path then my current one.

Would acceptable to email the hiring manager directly?

Comment: Agreed this question is quite specific. I would still mark as a duplicate though. Your friend might be able to get you some feedback from the hiring manager in a less direct way too.

Answer (score 7):

What are you looking to ask the hiring manager? If you want to ask them for feedback, that is very fair and should be expected on the hiring manager's part.

Always best to be conscious of their time but also be very direct. Something as simple as, "Thanks again for taking the time to interview me. Though things didn't seem to be a match, I'd really appreciate any brief feedback you have for me as I continue my job search.

Thanks again and best of luck in finding the right fit for the position!"